# Running python on many spot ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a python scraper script and I wish to deploy and run it on 100 ec2 (spot?) instances at the same time. It should run them for an hour and then stop all of them. How should i do it? Is there any aws service that will allow me to orchestrate it easily?

Answer (score 0):

When launching an Amazon EC2 instance (including those on Spot pricing), you can nominate the number of instances to launch. So, you can launch 100 spot instances with a single command.

One hour later, you could then issue a command to terminate the instances using a list of the instances returned by the first command.

Or, you could simply add a command in the startup script of each instance (issued via the User Data field) and waits for one hour and then issues a command to the operating system to shutdown (`sudo shutdown now -h`). This User Data script can also be used to install and run your scraper code on the instance.

I suggest that you experiment by launching just a single instance until you have things working the way you want.